# If $f(x) = Ax$, show that for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, the extreme $x_n = x_n(t)$ of polygon converges to $e^{At} x_0$.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ is a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_{k+1} = x_k + f(x_k)\Delta t$, $k= 0,1,...,n-1$, where $\Delta t = \frac{t}{n}$. A polygon whose points are the $x_i$ vérices, called Euler's polygon . If $f(x) = Ax$, show that for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, the extreme $x_n = x_n(t)$ of polygon converges to $e^{At} x_0$.

**Comments:**

The hint of the exercise is to show that $x_n(t) = (I + \frac{At}{n})^n x_0$

Have I proved that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (I + \frac{At}{n})^n = e^{At}$$
But I can not show that $x_n$ is the term that way. I did the following:

$x_1 = x_0 + f(x_0) \Delta t$,

$x_2 = x_1 + f(x_1) \Delta t = x_0 + (f(x_0) + f(x_1)) \Delta t$, ...

$x_n = x_{n-1} + f(x_{n-1}) \Delta t = x_0 + (\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} A x_i)) \frac{t}{n}$